# RestKit CoreData and Faults

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit

I am currently working on an app that consumes a Rest API and I am using a mix of EntityMapping and ObjectMapping because there are some static data that I prefer to be kept in a local storage vs other "live" data that I don't want to bother keeping.

I,ll try to summarize it as much as I can. So I am performing a standard `getObjectsAtPath` with the following class and mapping (I'll remove the extra un-needed stuff):

**PKNewsLocale.h**

```
@interface PKNewsLocale : NSObject
  @property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *identifier;

  // PKLanguage is a NSManagedObject kept in Core Data SQLite
  @property (strong, nonatomic) PKLanguage *language;
@end
```

**PKLanguage.h**

```
@interface PKLanguage : NSManagedObject
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * code;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * identifier;
// Other bunch of properties
@end
```

**Rest API JSON Response**

```
{
   id: 2,
   language: 2
}
```

**And the mapping part**

```
RKObjectMapping *getNewsLocaleMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[PKNewsLocale class]];
    [getNewsLocaleMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
            @"id" : @"identifier",
    }];

RKEntityMapping *language = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"language" inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];
    language.identificationAttributes = @[@"identifier"];
    [language addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"identifier"]];
    [getNewsLocaleMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"language" toKeyPath:@"language" withMapping:language]];
```

It is all working as expected. I have overriden the `setLanguage` function of PKNewsLocale and the language if fetched from the CoreData DB (thru the identifier) and is properly loaded.

The problem is that when I arrive on my ViewController and I try to access the object, the language entity is turned into a fault (I have implemented willTurnIntoFault and see that it goes throught it) and the data is never fetched back, resulting in a faulted PKLanguage entity where all properties are nil.

Is there something I am missing? Everywhere I read about faulted managed objects is that when we access any property of it, it should be back to realized state... but it doesn't seem to be the case.

**EDIT**

After digging through and with the help of Wain. I have been able to fix the problem by subclassing RKManagedObjectRequestOperation and adding the following line upon success :

`[wkSelf.managedObjectContext processPendingChanges];`

_and capturing a weak pointer on self before the block creation. Now I have the feeling this is an issue on RestKit side, I will post an issue on their Github.

Comment: Show your test and how you're trying to fire the fault. Be sure you know which thread you're on when looking at code running in the MO accessor methods...

Comment: @Wain I am simply trying to get the language identifier for some other logic in my view controller (i.e. `NSNumber* langId =  myVC.newsLocale.language.identifier`). This is done on the main thread. Most probably than not, the RestKit objects are created on some background threads. Could that be the problem?

Comment: They are created on a background thread and saved up to the main context.

Comment: Then do you have any idea on why they aren't un-faulted?

Comment: There isn't enough info. First, are you sure you have an object that's complete with data and merged into the main context? Are all of the parts linked together or is something missing? Log the thread and the content at each level during the test.

Comment: Edited the question with a work around fix. Thanks for you help, will transfer this to restkit's team I guess